# MMC cannot open the file *.msc

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, citrix, windows

On Windows Server 2008 R2 I have various admin consoles/snapins installed. All of these run correctly, whether I launch them directly or add them to MMC.

However, if I try to launch them from the command line or from a batch file I get the above error.

No errors or relevant information is logged in the event logs. I have tried deleting the files from AppData\MMC and have also tried re-registering msxml3.dll.

Any other suggestions?

PS the reason I need to do this is that I'm trying to publish them via Citrix.

Comment: from the CLI, are you executing them using an elevated command prompt?

Comment: @SpacemanSpiff - no, but I do get a UAC prompt to launch MMC anyway.

Comment: @SpacemanSpiff - just to verify, running with elevated privileges makes no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My next steps would be
a) trying to run the consoles in 32-bit environment as "mmc /32 compmgmt.msc" and if it doesn't help
b) running "sfc /scannow"

Comment: Hmm I was trying to force it to use 64 (32 bit won't work for some of the consoles). I'll try your suggestions and see how they go. Thanks